# Lower bound on dimension of fibres of a dominant mophism of irreducible affine varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

Whilst doing exercise $11.4.B$ of Ravi Vakil's "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry", I got stuck with the following problem (although I think that many of the hypotheses are unnecessary and a more general statement can be proved by reducing to something like this case):

> Let $X=\rm{Spec}(A)$ and $Y=\rm{Spec}(B)$ be irreducible affine $k-$varieties of dimension $m,n$ respectively and $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ be a dominant morphism. Then for any $q \in Y$, any irreducible component of the fibre $\pi^{-1}(q)$ has dimension at least $m-n$.

I know that for irreducible varieties codimension is the difference of dimensions, and that for $p \in X$ with $\pi(p) = q$, $\rm{codim}_Xp\leq \rm{codim}_Yq + \rm{codim}_{\pi^{-1}(q)}p$. If we take $p$ corresponding to the generic point of an irreducible component of $\pi^{-1}(q)$ then, putting these together gives that $m-n \leq \rm{dim}\bar{\{p\}}-\rm{dim}\bar{\{q\}}$ where the closures are taken in $X$ and $Y$ respectively. I'm having trouble showing that the right hand side is a lower bound for the dimension of the closure of $p$ in $\pi^{-1}(q)$, which is the dimension of the irreducible component that we want a lower bound for.

Algebraically this amounts to proving: given a prime $\mathfrak{q}$ of $B$ and a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ lying over $\mathfrak{q}$, there is a chain of primes going up from $\mathfrak{p}$ that all lie over $\mathfrak{q}$, of length at least $\rm{dim}(A/\mathfrak{p})-\rm{dim}(B/\mathfrak{q})$. This is easy to prove if $\mathfrak{q}$ is maximal (since then any maximal length chain of primes over $\mathfrak{p}$ will work), otherwise this difference just gives a lower bound for the number of times two consecutive primes in any maximal chain over $\mathfrak{p}$ pull back to the same prime in $B$.

**Edit:** A more general inequality than the one I gave in the second paragraph gives that for any $p$ mapping to $q$, $m-n \leq \rm{dim}\bar{p}-\rm{dim}\bar{q}+\rm{codim}_{\pi^{-1}(q)}p$. In particular, as suggested by Hoot in the comments, given a particular irreducible component of the fibre, one can take $p$ to correspond to a closed point lying in that component and no other, so that it's codimension is the dimension of that component. It then remains to show that $\rm{dim}\bar{\{p\}}-\rm{dim}\bar{\{q\}} \leq 0$.

Comment: It might be better to pick $p$ to be a closed point of $\pi^{-1}(q)$. If you force the term on the right to be zero it seems hard to extract any information about the fiber.

Comment: @Hoot I had thought about taking $p$ a closed point of the fibre, but then I'm not sure how to get information about any irreducible component of the fibre, you just get an equation with the dimension of the whole fibre...

Comment: For any irreducible component of $\pi^{-1}(q)$ you can choose $p$ to lie only on that irreducible component. I think that helps.

Comment: @Hoot Something like that could work if you could show that every irreducible component contains a closed point that lies in no other irreducible component (which will be true, actually, since the fibre is Noetherian so is a union of finitely many irreducible components in a unique way, so the union of all but one component will be a non-empty open set, necessarily a subset of the final component, and closed points in locally finite type $k$ schemes are dense, I think. I'll add something that works for more general $p$ then.

Comment: Right. This is what I had in mind. I don't think one needs to muck around with chains of primes.

Comment: @Hoot Given the edit then, it remains to show that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal lying over $\mathfrak{q}$, then there is some chain of primes going up from $\mathfrak{p}$ at least as long as a maximal chain going up from $\mathfrak{q}$.

Comment: @Hoot In fact I think this an equivalent algebraic statement, although perhaps it is easier to solve. I'm not sure how to avoid mucking about with primes (but that said, I'm not sure how to actually do anything with it either, just re-state the problem).

Comment: @ Hoot I think that $p$ is closed in the fibre, but not necessarily in $X$; it's a prime maximal with respect to lying over $\mathfrak{q}$, not just a maximal prime. For example, including the polynomial ring in one variable into the polynomial ring in two variables, $(Y)$ is a closed point of the fibre over $(0)$, but it is not a closed point of $X$.

Comment: @Hoot Okay, well, let me know if you come up with anything!

Comment: I think the point is that $p$ maps to $q$, so you get $k(q) \subset k(p)$ and compare transcendence degrees. These are the function fields of the closures.

Comment: @Hoot Great, that'll do it, thanks. I'll post a brief answer so that I can close the question then.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I'm glad it checks out.

Comment: @Hoot Actually, won't this just give the inequality $\rm{dim}\bar{\{p\}}-\rm{dim}\bar{\{q\}} \geq 0$, which is the opposite of what we want?

Comment: Yes, sorry for leading you on a wild goose chase. I really thought it would work. Here is a different idea: go back to choosing $p$ to be the generic point of an irreducible component of the fiber. Okay. We end up with $m-n \leq \dim \{p\}^- - \dim\{q\}^-$. Here the closures are in $X,Y$ respectively. Now, this last number is also $\operatorname{tr.deg}_k k(p) - \operatorname{tr.deg}_k k(q) = \operatorname{tr.deg}_{k(q)} k(p)$. Now $k(p)$ is also the residue field of $p$ on $\pi^{-1}(q)$, and this last transcendence degree should compute the dimension of the component of $\pi^{-1}(q)$.

Comment: @Hoot Ah, that's great, thanks! I didn't think to use transcendence degree to compute the dimension of components of the fibre. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out on this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in the question, it suffices to prove that for any $q \in Y$ and $p\in X$ corresponding to an irreducible component of the fibre, that $\rm{dim}_X\bar{\{p\}}-\rm{dim}_Y\bar{\{q\}} = \rm{dim}_{\pi^{-1}(q)}\bar{\{p\}}$. This is in fact true for all $p$ in the fibre:

By construction $\pi^{-1}(q)$ is a finite type $\kappa_q$-scheme, and so we can compute the dimension of irreducible components by computing the transcendence degree of the residue field at the generic points over $\kappa_q$. But for any $p \in \pi^{-1}(q)$, we have that the map of local rings $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\pi^{-1}(q),p}$ is surjective, and so the residue field of $p$ in $\pi^{-1}(q)$ is isomorphic to the residue field in $X$. Thus we have that $\rm{dim}_{\pi^{-1}(q)}\bar{{\{p\}}} = \rm{tr.deg}_{\kappa_q}(\kappa_p)=\rm{tr.deg}_{k}(\kappa_p)-\rm{tr.deg}_{k}(\kappa_q)=\rm{dim}_X\bar{\{p\}}-\rm{dim}_Y\bar{\{q\}}$ as desired.