# Dimension of Fibers of a Morphism "Proof" Contradicts Later Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm working on Exercise 3.22(b) in Hartshorne which states:

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a dominant morphism of integral schemes of a finite type over a field $k$. Let $e = \dim X - \dim Y$ be the *relative dimension* of $X$ over $Y$. For any point $y \in f(X)$, show that every irreducible component of the fiber $X_y$ has dimension $\geq e$.

The proof I came up with is:
Let $y =f(x)$ for some $x \in X$ and let $Z'$ denote some irreducible component of $f^{-1}(y)$ with generic point $r$. Let $Z = \overline{\{r\}}$, where closure is done in $X$. Then, by exercise 3.22(a)*, $\mathrm{codim}(Z, X) \leq \mathrm{codim}(Y', Y)$ where $Y' := \overline{\{y\}}$ with closure done in $Y$. Then because codimension is the difference of dimension for varieties, $\dim(X) - \dim(Z) \leq \dim(Y) - \dim(Y')$, so rearranging we obtain $e \leq \dim(Z) - \dim(Y') = \dim(Z') - \dim(Y')$ because [the dimension of any locally closed set is the dimension of its closure](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/145Page/handouts/dimension.pdf). Thus in particular $e \leq \dim(Z')$."

My problem with this proof is that if $y$ is not a closed point, this says that $e < \dim(Z')$, which would in particular violate a theorem that says that for any morphism of integral $k$ varieties, there is a nonempty open set $U \subset Y$ such that for all $y \in U$ the fiber above $y$ is pure dimension exactly $e$. (See Theorem 11.4.1 [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf).)

What precisely is going wrong here?

Edit: Given the comments of [this question,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808964/lower-bound-on-dimension-of-fibres-of-a-dominant-mophism-of-irreducible-affine-v) I suspect it is not the case that $\dim(Z) = \dim(Z')$, so is the theorem about dimension of a locally closed subset false?

*Exercise 3.22(a) states that with the above setup, if $Y'$ is a closed irreducible subset of $Y$ whose generic point $\eta'$ is contained in $f(X)$, and $Z$ is any irreducible component of $Y'$ with $\eta' \in f(Z)$, then $\mathrm{codim}(Z, X) \leq \mathrm{codim}(Y', Y)$.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on these kinds of arguments, but are you sure that the theorem you cited from Vakil applies here? If $y$ is a non-closed point, say the generic point of a curve in $Y$, shouldn't the fiber be something like the generic point of the preimage of the curve? Which I'm fairly certain is not reduced. But again I'm rusty so if this sounds plausible you should make it rigorous and post it as an answer if it works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the theorem applies, because the proof of it appeals to the essentially exact statement of 3.22b (in fact, this was where I was originally working out of, but I found the same question in Hartshorne and figured more people had read that). For a correct proof of the exercise, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808964/lower-bound-on-dimension-of-fibres-of-a-dominant-mophism-of-irreducible-affine-v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! An irreducible component of a fiber of the map $\pi: X \to Y$ need not be locally closed in $X$--for example, consider the identity morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(k[x]) \to \mathrm{Spec}(k[x])$, whose fiber at the generic point is, of course, the generic point, which is not locally closed (and is not even constructible).